# Programmatic Comparison of SQL Server Versions using TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

To give some background on this, I've got a handful of 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008R2 and 2012 servers in my environment.  I'm trying to identify, programmatically via TSQL, which servers are of a sufficient level to tie into the sys.dm_db_partition_stats.  To make things complicated, MS introduced this feature officially with **SP2 on 2008 R2**, **SP1 with 2012**, and were nice enough to include it in the **RTM for 2014**.  What I want to do is determine which version the current SQL Server is that I'm running said query on and then compare if that version is equal to or higher than the aforementioned SQL Server versions/patch levels.  If so I'll use the new DMV, otherwise I'll use the depreciated sys.sysindexes DMV.

Just to warn you, this isn't as simple as looking at the major product version.  For instance, if I have a SQL Server 2012 RTM server, it is at a higher level than the SQL 2008 R2 SP2 level, but it's not of a sufficient level on the 2012 product line, so this routine has to have some logic explicitly built in.

I tried sidestepping this and querying the sys.all_views view, but ironically the sys.dm_db_partition_stats DMV was included with SQL Server as early as 2005, though trying to query it results in a query parse failure.

I could use a "poor practice" workaround in place that runs some DSQL within a TRY CATCH block, but frankly that truly is a bad approach and I'd rather do it the right way.

So, to my question: Does anyone have a procedure that they can share that will programmatically return a true/false if the SQL Server Version fits into a certain Patchset level or higher?

I've got no problems coming up with said routine myself, but was hoping someone out there already had something similar I could tie into.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about a handful of options regarding storing the various build versions of SQL, using PowerShell, etc. until I realized my real problem was converting the Build Version into something that was easily comparable.  In NVARCHAR format, a build version of 9.xxx is actually larger than 12.xxx as it's doing an alphanumeric comparison (e.g. 9 > 1) instead of a numeric comparison (e.g. 12 > 9).  This always skewed my results in a bad way, so what I ended up doing was I originally came up with a routine to convert the Build Version into a 4-column query result I could easily run numeric comparison logic against, in regards to the Major, Minor, Build, and Revision versions.  I throw everything into an IF EXISTS block and I get my true/false logic as required.

Then via another forum, the PARSENAME() function was mentioned, and that is the much much easier route to take:

```
-- Will Wrap an IF EXISTS check around this query
SELECT 1
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS NVARCHAR(128)), 4) AS INT) AS Major, 
            CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS NVARCHAR(128)), 3) AS INT) AS Minor, 
            CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS NVARCHAR(128)), 2) AS INT) AS Build, 
            CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS NVARCHAR(128)), 1) AS INT) AS Revision
) t
WHERE (t.Major >= 10 AND t.Minor >= 50 AND t.Build >= 4000)
    OR (t.Major >= 11 AND t.Build >= 3000)
    OR (t.Major >= 12)
```

Here's the original code I came up with in case anyone cares.  One approach using a Table Variable; the other a CTE.

The only downside here is it's not viable in any version older than 2005 because of the PIVOT function, whereas the PARSENAME function doesn't have the same issue.

```
-- NOTE: General Split Funcationality via http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

-- ### Table Var ### --

DECLARE @ProductVersion TABLE
(
    RowNum  INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Val INT
)

INSERT INTO @ProductVersion (Val)
SELECT y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(128)')
FROM 
( 
SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
    + REPLACE(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS NVARCHAR(128)), '.', '</i><i>') 
    + '</i>').query('.')
) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)

-- Will Wrap an IF EXISTS check around this query
SELECT 1
FROM(
    SELECT MAX([1]) AS Major, MAX([2]) AS Minor, MAX([3]) AS Build, MAX([4]) AS Revision
    FROM @ProductVersion pv
    PIVOT (MAX(pv.Val) FOR RowNum IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])) AS PivotTable
) t
WHERE (t.Major >= 10 AND t.Minor >= 50 AND t.Build >= 4000)
    OR (t.Major >= 11 AND t.Build >= 3000)
    OR (t.Major >= 12)

GO


-- ### CTE ### --

-- RowNum workaround per http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/383888/fully-support-position-in-xquery
WITH ProductVersion AS
(
    SELECT y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'int') AS Val, row_number() over (partition by 0 order by nullif(0 * y.i.value('count(.)','int'), 0)) AS RowNum
    FROM 
    ( 
    SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
        + REPLACE(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS NVARCHAR(128)), '.', '</i><i>') 
        + '</i>').query('.')
    ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
)

-- Will Wrap an IF EXISTS check around this query
SELECT 1
FROM(
    SELECT MAX([1]) AS Major, MAX([2]) AS Minor, MAX([3]) AS Build, MAX([4]) AS Revision
    FROM ProductVersion pv
    PIVOT (MAX(pv.Val) FOR RowNum IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])) AS PivotTable
) t
WHERE (t.Major >= 10 AND t.Minor >= 50 AND t.Build >= 4000)
    OR (t.Major >= 11 AND t.Build >= 3000)
    OR (t.Major >= 12)
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on your description of the versions that can run dm_db_partition_stats, this would tell you 1 if you can run it, 0 if you can't.

```
SELECT CASE
     WHEN @@VERSION LIKE '%7.00.623%' THEN 0
     WHEN @@VERSION LIKE '%7.00.699%' THEN 0
     WHEN @@VERSION LIKE '%7.00.842%' THEN 0
     WHEN @@VERSION LIKE '%7.00.960%' THEN 0
     WHEN @@VERSION LIKE '%7.00.0063%' THEN 0
     WHEN @@VERSION LIKE '%8.00.094%' THEN 0
     WHEN @@VERSION LIKE '%8.00.384%' THEN 0
     WHEN @@VERSION LIKE '%8.00.532%' THEN 0
     WHEN @@VERSION LIKE '%8.00.760%' THEN 0
     WHEN @@VERSION LIKE '%8.00.2039%' THEN 0
     WHEN @@VERSION LIKE '%9.00.0399.06%' THEN 0
     WHEN @@VERSION LIKE '%9.00.2047%' THEN 0
     WHEN @@VERSION LIKE '%9.00.3042%' THEN 0
     WHEN @@VERSION LIKE '%9.00.4035%' THEN 0
     WHEN @@VERSION LIKE '%9.00.5000%' THEN 0
     WHEN @@VERSION LIKE '%00.00.0600.22%' THEN 0
     WHEN @@VERSION LIKE '%00.00.2530%' THEN 0
     WHEN @@VERSION LIKE '%00.00.4000%' THEN 0
     WHEN @@VERSION LIKE '%00.00.5500%' THEN 0
     WHEN @@VERSION LIKE '%00.50.0600.0%' THEN 0
     WHEN @@VERSION LIKE '%00.50.2500' THEN 0
     WHEN @@VERSION LIKE '%00.00.2000.6%' THEN 0
     ELSE 1
 END
```

Comment: This doesn't account for CUs or hotfixes... and frankly I don't want to maintain a huge list of release numbers.  Thanks for the input though!